# Working with Google Cloud Tasks API Pushing Queue, everything is set up. The task was queued successfully but doesn't hit the target API successfully

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, heroku, google-cloud-tasks

here is the details, i am using python client for this purpose and jab being added in the queue successfully. with target-address as an API end point, but unfortunately target API is not being called by queued task. error status is FAILED_PRECONDITION.

```
                    task = {
                        "http_request": {
                            "http_method": "POST",
                            "url": "https://something.herokuapp.com/report-generator-testing/",
                            "body": json.dumps(task_payload).encode("utf-8"),
                        }
                    }

                    response = client.create_task(request={"parent": parent, "task": task})
```

here is the log for this error.

```
{
insertId: "1fw8pmsd6byb"
jsonPayload: {
attemptResponseLog: {
scheduleTime: "2023-08-31T12:42:13.151928Z"
dispatchCount: "3"
responseCount: "3"
status: "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
maxAttempts: 0
targetType: "HTTP"
attemptDuration: "0.139324s"
targetAddress: "POST https://something.herokuapp.com/something-testing/"
retryTime: "2023-08-31T12:42:14.081003Z"
}
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.tasks.logging.v1.TaskActivityLog"
task: "projects/something/locations/something/queues/something"
}
logName: "projects/something/logs/cloudtasks.googleapis.com%2Ftask_operations_log"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-08-31T12:42:13.965234343Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "ERROR"
timestamp: "2023-08-31T12:42:13.681123763Z"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message? Can you provide any documentation that you follow?